# Update values in one table based on contents of another

Tags: oracle, join, update

Software Name: Oracle SQL Developer Version 17.2.0.188

I have three tables: `orders`, `order_details`, and `products`.

I wanted to run a query to update `units_in_stock` in the `products` table based on `quantity` in `order_details`, where the associated `orders` row has been marked as shipped, and has a shipping date.

Here's what I tried:

```
UPDATE Products SET (Products.Unit_In_Stock = Products.Unit_In_Stock - Order_Details.Quantity)
INNER JOIN (
    Orders INNER JOIN Order_Details ON Orders.Order_ID = Order_Details.Order_ID
    ) ON Products.Product_ID = Order_Details.Product_ID
WHERE (
        ((Orders.Shipped_Date) IS NOT NULL)
        AND ((Orders.This_Order_Was_Shipped) = "YES")
        );
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 45
```

Line 1, Column 45 is the equal sign in the very first statement that said

```
Products.Unit_In_Stock = Products.Unit_In_Stock - Order_Details.Quantity
```

Can you help me get this working?

Comment: What's with all the extra brackets?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this should do it for Oracle:

```
UPDATE Products 
SET Products.Unit_In_Stock = Products.Unit_In_Stock - 
(
    SELECT Order_Details.Quantity
    FROM Orders 
        INNER JOIN Order_Details 
        ON Orders.Order_ID = Order_Details.Order_ID
    WHERE Products.Product_ID = Order_Details.Product_ID 
    AND (Orders.Shipped_Date IS NOT NULL) 
    AND (Orders.This_Order_Was_Shipped = "YES")
)
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT Order_Details.Quantity
    FROM Orders 
        INNER JOIN Order_Details 
        ON Orders.Order_ID = Order_Details.Order_ID
    WHERE Products.Product_ID = Order_Details.Product_ID 
    AND (Orders.Shipped_Date IS NOT NULL) 
    AND (Orders.This_Order_Was_Shipped = "YES")
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your situation looks similar to this:

```
-- tables for testing
create table products
as
select 
  1 as product_id
, 100 as unit_in_stock
from dual ; 

create table orders
as
select 
  100 as order_id 
, 'YES' as this_order_was_shipped
, to_date('2017-09-14', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as shipped_date 
from dual;

create table order_details
as
select
  100 as order_id
, 1 as product_id
, 25 as quantity
from dual;
```

The tables now contain the following rows:

```
select * from products;

PRODUCT_ID  UNIT_IN_STOCK
1           100

select * from orders;

ORDER_ID  THIS_ORDER_WAS_SHIPPED  SHIPPED_DATE
100       YES                     14-SEP-17

select * from order_details;

ORDER_ID  PRODUCT_ID  QUANTITY
100       1           25
```

The update could look something like ...

```
update products 
set  products.unit_in_stock = (
  select 
    products.unit_in_stock - OD.Quantity
  from orders O
    join order_details OD on O.order_id = OD.order_id
  where O.shipped_date is not null
    and O.this_order_was_shipped = 'YES'
) 
where product_id = 1;
```

After executing the UPDATE, the PRODUCTS table contains:

```
select * from products;
PRODUCT_ID  UNIT_IN_STOCK
1           75
```

See dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=357ea92957d98a789696bbff98c84b83).

**ADDITIONAL questions and answers:**

*1) The code that you wrote have OD.Quantity instead of Orders.Quantity. How does the program know that OD.Quantity is Orders.Quantity ?*

In my example, the "quantity" of an ordered product is stored in the OrderDetails table. (The ORDERS table does not contain a quantity).

*2) You use O instead of Orders. How does the program know that O is Orders ?*

Table aliases.  When you write something like SELECT ... FROM mytable M ... , then the letter M can be used as a "short name" / alias for the table.  Usually, this makes queries easier to code (and read).

*3) When I replace your code using Orders, and Order_Details instead of O and OD I got an error. Why is that ?*

I don't know - as you did not put any examples on dbfiddle (or into the question itself).  However, if you replace all Os and ODs with the full table names, it should work.  See dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e71f497827d141ac668df2beaa281cf3).  Notice that there is a WHERE clause for the UPDATE, too (this is needed, otherwise *all* rows in the PRODUCTS table would be updated).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're still having some problems with the query Stefan provided. There are potential issues as you expand outside of his test case.

As written, his query does not handle:

- Tying the `order_details` rows to the right row from `products`,
- Multiple rows in `order_details` that should be used when adjusting the `units_in_stock`, and
- Cases where there's no `order_details` rows to update a particular row from `products`.

Here's a modified version of his query that handles these issues:

```
update products 
set  products.unit_in_stock = products.unit_in_stock - NVL( (
  select 
    SUM(OD.Quantity)
  from orders O
    join order_details OD on O.order_id = OD.order_id
  where O.shipped_date is not null
    and O.this_order_was_shipped = 'YES'
    and OD.product_id = products.product_id
) , 0)
;
```

And, here's the corresponding [dbfiddle link](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4097a03aa36868b219cf4060cf6aff69)

Notes:

- I covered the possibility of multiple rows from `order_details` for a given `product_id` by taking the `SUM` of `OD.quantity`.
- I covered the possibility that a `product_id` would not have any matches by checking if we got back a NULL value from the subquery, and substituting 0 for the NULL.
- I added a check to the subquery's `WHERE` clause to make sure that for any given row in `products`, we *only* look at `order_details` with the same `product_id`.

**Important note:** The above code does *nothing* to prevent rows from `order_details` from being used to update `products.units_in_stock` *more than once*. You should *not* apply this, as is, more than once.

To fix this, you need to do one of the following:

- Add an `UPDATE` trigger to `orders` that checks if the order has been changed so that it did *not* meet both conditions (marked as shipped, and has a shipping date) before, and it does now; if so, update `products.units_in_stock` from all related `order_details` records. If an order can be initially added as shipped, with a shipping date, then you'd need this same code in an `INSERT` trigger as well. (Note that even this is not sufficient to protect things, if `this_order_was_shipped` can change, or `shipped_date` can be set back to NULL. Ideally, if that happened, you'd need to reverse the process, restoring the `quantity` from the `order_details` record back to `products.units_in_stock`);
- Set permissions so that `orders` and `order_details` can *only* be inserted or modified via stored procedures, and manage the changes in the stored procedure (some people don't like triggers); or
- Add a flag of some sort to the `orders` or `order_details` table, to indicate that the items have already been adjusted out of `products.units_in_stock`, update the query to ignore rows with the flag, and set the flag when you run this query.

---

With respect to your follow-up questions:

> 1) The code that you wrote have OD.Quantity instead of Orders.Quantity.
>      How does the program know that OD.Quantity is Orders.Quantity ?
>
> 2) You use O instead of Orders.
>      How does the program know that O is Orders ?
>
> 3) When I replace your code using Orders, and Order_Details
>      instead of O and OD I got an error. Why is that ?

The `FROM` clause establishes `O` as an alias for `Orders` and `OD` as an alias for `Order_Details`.

So, the `FROM` clause tells the engine that `OD.Quantity` is `Order_Deteails.Quantity` (not `Orders.Quantity`, by the way), and that `O` means `Orders`.

If you need to include the same table twice in a `FROM` clause, aliases are absolutely necessary. Imagine that your order had two fields for employee IDs - one for the person who took the order, and one for the person who took the cancellation of the order. If you needed both of those employee's names, you'd need to join that table to `Orders` twice - something like:

```
SELECT O.orderno
      ,Employees.emp_name as Took_Order
      ,cancel_emp.emp_name as Took_Cancel
  FROM Orders O
         INNER JOIN Employees ON (O.order_taken_by = Employees.emp_id)
         LEFT  JOIN Employees cancel_emp ON (O.cancel_taken_by = cancel_emp.emp_id)
;
```

Without a separate name for `cancel_emp`, how could the engine know which `emp_name` to put where?

If you left the aliases in place, but tried to use the original table names elsewhere, like this:

```
update products 
set  products.unit_in_stock = (
  select 
    products.unit_in_stock - order_details.Quantity
  from orders O
    join order_details OD on orders.order_id = order_details.order_id
  where orders.shipped_date is not null
    and orders.this_order_was_shipped = 'YES'
    and OD.product_id = products.product_id
)
where product_id = 1;
```

Then the problem is presumably due to the fact that, once an alias is in place, Oracle is going to expect you to just use the alias. If you tell it that the `Orders` table should be referenced as `O`, and then try to user `Orders` somewhere, it's going to think that's a different table, and not recognize it. If you don't want to use an alias, make sure you drop it in the `FROM` clause:

```
update products 
set  products.unit_in_stock = (
  select 
    products.unit_in_stock - order_details.Quantity
  from orders
    join order_details on orders.order_id = order_details.order_id
  where orders.shipped_date is not null
    and orders.this_order_was_shipped = 'YES'
    and order_details.product_id = products.product_id
)
where product_id = 1;
```

Then, everything should work as expected.

Comment: The code below does work, but it update the field Products.units_in_stock for all records to null. This is not what I intended. Instead, I want to update the Products.units_in_stock to be Products.units_in_stock = Products.units_in_stock - Order_Details.Quantity, if orders.shipped_date is not null and orders.this_order_was_shipped = 'YES'

Comment: I was just using the queries stefan had provided, as examples of what you were asking about in your follow-up. However, I have now added a revised version of stefan's query, to fix a few issues like the one you ran into. See my updated answer above.